# ui router if resolve fails why do load the view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

May be I miss something but 
if I set a state like this:

```
.state('session_register', {
        url: '/privatearea',
        resolve: {
            isLogged: function(Session){
                return Session.isLogged();
            } 
        },
        templateUrl: 'private/user.html',
        controller:'UserController'
 })
```

if isLogged return a 401 status (resolve fails)

even if I don't really see the user.html in the browser

the partial is just loaded (firebug)

So I'm wondering

Is it the wanted behaviour ?

Is there a way to not load partial

when a resolve fails ?

I've got also an httpInterceptor

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$location',
    function($q, $location) {
      return {
        'response': function(response) {
          if (response.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/auth/login');
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
          return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        'responseError': function(rejection) {

          if (rejection.status === 401) {
            $location.url('/auth/login');
            return $q.reject(rejection);
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }

      };
    }
  ])
//Http Interceptor to check auth failures for XHR requests
.config(['$httpProvider',
  function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
  }
]);
```

### END UP

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q','$location',function ($q,$location) {
        var canceller = $q.defer();
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                // promise that should abort the request when resolved.
                config.timeout = canceller.promise;
                return config;
            },
            'response': function(response) {
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    canceller.resolve('Unauthorized'); 
                    $location.url('/user/signin');
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
                if (rejection.status === 403) {
                    canceller.resolve('Forbidden');  
                    $location.url('/');
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }

        };
    }
    ])
    //Http Intercpetor to check auth failures for xhr requests
   .config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    }]);
```

it works  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is by design. Apart from an extra bandwidth, there is no need to block the template loading, otherwise the view will complete slower.

And there is no way to change this behavior too. From the source code:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/0.2.10/src/state.js#L1158

```
dst.resolve = $resolve.resolve(state.resolve, locals, dst.resolve, state);
var promises = [ dst.resolve.then(function (globals) {
  dst.globals = globals;
}) ];
if (inherited) promises.push(inherited);

// Resolve template and dependencies for all views.
forEach(state.views, function (view, name) {
  var injectables = (view.resolve && view.resolve !== state.resolve ? view.resolve : {});
  injectables.$template = [ function () {
    return $view.load(name, { view: view, locals: locals, params: $stateParams, notify: false }) || '';
  }];

  promises.push($resolve.resolve(injectables, locals, dst.resolve, state).then(function (result) {
    // References to the controller (only instantiated at link time)
    if (isFunction(view.controllerProvider) || isArray(view.controllerProvider)) {
      var injectLocals = angular.extend({}, injectables, locals);
      result.$$controller = $injector.invoke(view.controllerProvider, null, injectLocals);
    } else {
      result.$$controller = view.controller;
    }
    // Provide access to the state itself for internal use
    result.$$state = state;
    result.$$controllerAs = view.controllerAs;
    dst[name] = result;
  }));
});

// Wait for all the promises and then return the activation object
return $q.all(promises).then(function (values) {
  return dst;
});
```

A promise from `state.resolve`:

```
$resolve.resolve(state.resolve, locals, dst.resolve, state);
```

and `$view.load` (which make a http request for the `templateUrl`):

```
$view.load(name, { view: view, locals: locals, params: $stateParams, notify: false })
```

not wait for each other to finished first, it happens in pararell, and used in the return statement:

```
return $q.all(promises).then(function (values) {
```

Hope this clear things up.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Even if we can't stop the request from being fired, we can abort it as soon as it is unnecessary : )